# Should we have well explained Q&A(s) for basic Minecraft command translations?

Tags: discussion, minecraft

There is a huge list of commands available in both [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) and [minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition) that have the ability to be translated between the two versions. Recently, I had the pleasure of [answering a poorly received question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/389311/can-minecraft-be-commands-be-converted-to-je-commands/389314#389314) related to the translation of an `execute` command, where the translation wasn't exactly direct, but available documentation defined how to do it rather easily.

I believe it would be beneficial to explain basic translations in detail for all commands that are available in both versions. Not just translations from BE to JE though, the reverse should also be explained because BE commands are less powerful than JE commands and this can lead to some serious confusion for users.

I would like to explain some of these translations (at least the BE to JE side of things), in a way that the most common users can understand. Doing so will *help* prevent (not eradicate) potentially duplicate questions about basic translations in the future.

However, I have a few mental dilemmas, the biggest of which is simply:

- Should I do this in the first place?

If the answer to that is yes, then:

- Should it be one or many Q&As?

Mentally, my first thought is that it should be *one* large Q&A because it really is just one question. However, this results in information overload, and can get hard to search. Even in alphabetical order, the answer to the post would be incredibly long and specific commands would be harder to find for common users.

My ultimate mindset on it is that it should be multiple Q&As where each one is focused on a specific command. The advantage here is each Q&A can contain the translation from BE to JE and JE to BE in the same answer, searchability is improved, risk of duplicates is lowered, and there's less information to absorb making it more useful overall.

---

Should we have well explained Q&A for basic translations? If so, should it be one post or many?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is a good idea and would recommend doing multiple questions.

The way I view these types of posts is more meant as an endpoint that answers the problem in a general manner, where other posts can then direct to (i.e. be marked as a duplicate of).

With that in mind, a user asking the question wants an answer to their issue, not a general list of command translations they have to dig through.  Having separate questions should also help when the user is first asking, as the post for their command will have a better chance at showing up from a search as a meaningful response for the asker.

Now, I'm not familiar with all the various commands across the versions of Minecraft, but I imagine there's a lot.  So, rather than flood in a post for every one, focus on the most commonly asked about.  Also, if a couple are typically used together or overlap, then you might consider putting those together into one post.

Answer (score 2):

I'm split on this.

On one hand, that is a legitimate question. Stuff has changed, and well you need to find the new command somewhere.

Having those in well formulated questions and answered thouroughly can help users and bring traffic to the site.

But I don't know why, I feel like creating questions like those in kind of a preemption of a future question rubs me the wrong way. I think its because my brain is wired that this is a site where one asks, and the community answers. Not letting the one ask seems, illogical somehow. But the option is there when you create a question, to immediately answer your own question. Wonder if theres a stat to pull somewhere about how much its used.

So its a good idea, and I would not mind people building wikis on this site. It would probably boost growth doing so. But for some reason, it bugs me. Is it only me?

EDIT: To complete, I think that the question was poorly received because its something that usually you could google and quickly find your answer. This community has a 'search first, and if you don't find anything, ask here' mentality, and questions that don't show that you looked around first tend to be downvoted.

EDIT 2: Over time, while thinking about this I think I figured what is bugging me. Its that its the Q&A thing is the thing that makes Arqade unique. We are not gamefaqs, where someone just screams their info into the void without input. People ask because they need help, and we, as a community, help them solve what they cant. Think thats what my brain is hooking onto and why I'm bugged about it.

But seeing as on one side I think such an approach might help drive some traffic to this site, instead of waiting for the particular question that never was answered anywhere else, is bigger than just me being bugged.

Comment: I actually love your points here, so thank you for the feedback! I feel the same way about answering my own questions a lot of the time, unless it's something I spent hours on and it hadn't been asked yet. I'm also curious about the stat on self-answering, but I don't have access to that.  In reference to the poorly received question, I concur entirely; I believe the OP could've put more effort into demonstrating what they were trying to accomplish, and what they had already tried. Would've saved me some time in my answer, or someone else could've answered faster.